# "He lay on the bed gazing up at the ceiling." - Is this sentence from a dictionary correct?

Tags: grammar, verbs

In the [definition article of "gaze"](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/gaze_1) (MacMillan Dictionary) I found the following example sentence:

> He lay on the bed gazing up at the ceiling.

I cannot figure out what form "he lay" should be. My alternatives are "he lays" or "he laid" but not "he lay".

Is that sentence correct? If yes: what form is "he lay"?

---

Ohhh! After reading the answers (thx!), I found the source of my confusion: in this online dictionary you can click on each word and you would be forwarded to its definition. Clicking on "lay" in this sentence forwards to ["lay (verb)"](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/lay_1) what is obviously a tricky linking error of the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lay in this case is the past of "lie", which is an intransitive verb. The difficulty occurs because "lay" can be a form of two different verbs which have similar meanings:

1. lay, laid, laid (transitive): to put someone or something down in a careful way, especially so that they are lying flat https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/lay_1
2. lie, lay, lain (intransitive): to be in a position in which your body is flat on a surface such as the floor or a bed
   https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/lie_1

Even native speakers get tripped up on the proper forms. "Lain" in many cases sounds old-fashioned to some people.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the sentence is correct.

*He lay* is the **simple past** of the verb *lie*, which means to recline (like one does on a bed).

Unfortunately, your alternatives deal with another verb, *lay*, which means to put something on top of something else (like one does on a shelf).

> He **lies** on the bed. *He **lays** the book on the shelf.* *(present)*
>
> He **lay** on the bed. *He **laid** the book on the shelf. (simple past)*
>
> He **had lain** on the bed. *He **had laid** the book on the shelf. (pluperfect)*

If you're still confused, [this resource](http://www.chompchomp.com/rules/irregularrules02.htm) may help you.