# Two multiple choice test about reduced adjective (relative) clause and meaning

Tags: grammar, word-meaning, reduced-relative-clauses

> 1. The man ......... beside the host is guest.
>
> a. seating | b. who seats | c. seated | d. who seated

I can't choose the answer between a or c. they both seem right to me.

> 2. The glasses .......... on the floor belonged to my grandmother
>
> a. lied | b. lain | c. laid | d. lying

In this test, I'm not sure between c or d.

Note that in addition to grammar, their meaning must be correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The man **seated** beside the host is the guest.

*Seated* is an adjective meaning *on a chair*.

- *Seating* comes from the verb *to seat*, meaning *to provide chairs to people* (**NOT** *to sit*, which means *to put oneself on a chair*).
- *Who seats* also comes from the verb *to seat*, and would mean that the man is giving chairs near the host.
- *Who seated* is just the simple past of *who seats*, and would mean that the man was giving chairs near the host.

---

> The glasses **lying** on the floor belonged to my grandmother.

*Lying* is an adjective that comes from the verb *to lie*, meaning *to be flat on a surface*.

- *Lied* is the simple past of the verb *to lie*, which, in this case, means *to not tell the truth* (this is one of the two meanings of the verb *to lie*).
- *Lain* is the past participle of the verb *to lie* (the correct version), but it can't be used in this sentence because it requires the auxiliary verb *to have* (either *have lain* or *had lain*).
- *Laid* is the simple past of the verb *to lay*, which means *to put something on top of something else* (this verb is commonly confused with *to lie*).

I understand that this may be extremely confusing. Don't worry, though, because even native English speakers get confused over the difference between *to lay* and *to lie*.

I provided an explanation [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/148723/he-lay-on-the-bed-gazing-up-at-the-ceiling-is-this-sentence-from-a-dictiona/148727#148727) about a month ago that may help you if you are still confused.

Comment: Helpful and polite answer. Nice to see folks offering encouragement to learners.

Comment: "The man *sitting* beside the host" is also a valid construction. @titansarus may have been confusing this word with a.

Comment: @WesToleman That's funny because I put that in my original draft, replacing the answers with _sitting_, _who sits_, and _who sat_, but it seemed very lengthy and I omitted it to better focus on the question.